# Vscode not showing any available device for flutter

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code

My `vscode` was previously showing devices. But now it does not show any available devices.  However in the terminal if i run `flutter run` then it show all the available devices thats means all the devices are connected.  When i press run i.e. `Start Debugging F5` in `vscode` then nothing happens. I have already installed flutter extension in vscode also.

[image]

Not any device name is shown in the bottom bar in `vscode` as shown in above picture.

Answer (score 1):

I just deleted my `Flutter` directory and installed again. It is working now.

Answer (score 0):

My issue is i updated flutter version v2.10 to v3.0.2 but my mac is support only Xcode 12.4 but v3.0.2 required Xcode 13. So i downgrade the flutter version then simulator showing in VS-code.

**Just run flutter doctor -v it shows the error.**

***✗ Flutter requires Xcode 13 or higher.***

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command on the terminal

flutter doctor -v

Answer (score 0):

```
For macOS Only:
```

When you get a pop-up like `"X-code" is trying to install....` then Please allow it. If denied once then vscode will show No device. Also flutter doctor command will not return anything. Restart the system and open vscode, now it will ask the same dialogue again. Now Allow it by entering your password.

Answer (score -1):

If you're on mac go on terminal and type

```
open -a simulator
```

Else if on windows open your android studio and start your andriod simulator

Comment: All my simulator and devices are already running and connected. But Vscode not detecting anyone.